# ASP.NET FormView fails to execute a stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I encounter difficulties to update an item into an ASP.NET GridView (old code).

My stored procedure can be simplified to:

```
UPDATE myTable  SET FieldA = @FieldA, FieldB = @FieldB, FieldC = @FieldC    WHERE Id = @Id
```

My DataSource is a s follows:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:wsg_DataWriter %>"
    SelectCommand="MySelectSP" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand="MyUpdateSP" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Id" QueryStringField="Id" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="idWsgProgrammeOption" QueryStringField="idWsgProgrammeOption" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My FormView is as follows :

```
          <asp:FormView ID="FV" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id"  DataSourceID="DS"   >
        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TB_FieldA" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FieldA") %>' />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IB_FieldB" runat="server" CommandName="UpdateProgramme" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
                             ImageUrl='<%# (!Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("FieldB"))) ? "~/1.gif" : "~/2.gif" %>' OnCommand="On_FieldB"/>

                       <asp:TextBox ID="TB_FieldC" T runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FieldC") %>' /> 

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="i_imgbtnEnregistrer" runat="server" AlternateText="Enregistrer"
                            CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/admindefaut/image/bouton/enregitrer.gif" OnClick="OnClick"/>

        </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:FormView >
```

It does not work: I suppose the stored procedure fails to execute.

I am very close of having it working. The issue seems to come from the binding of FieldB into the SP.

It works fine if I change it this way:

```
<UpdateParameters>
             <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="idWsgProgrammeOption" QueryStringField="idWsgProgrammeOption" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

-->

```
 <UpdateParameters>
             <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="idWsgProgrammeOption" QueryStringField="idWsgProgrammeOption" />
<asp:Parameter Name="FieldB" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

And add:

```
 protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    FV.UpdateParameters["FieldB"].DefaultValue=  "1";
 }
```

So somehow, .NET manages to get correct values of FieldA and FieldB and pass them to the SP. But it does not manage to grab the correct FieldB value.

Can anyone give me a hand there? I would need to pass the correct FieldB value value without using the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding FieldB to a hidden field on your aspx page using the Bind keyword, not Eval.